# ViewController background color won't change

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've started a new project, and I'm trying to create it using MVC and a programmatic UI.

I'm trying to set a `ViewController`'s background color, but it just won't change.

I have already written my programmatic UI, but I changed the background color in the `ViewController` itself, but not from the `view`.

This is my `view`:

```swift
import UIKit

class ReportView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.appColors.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This is my `ViewController`:

```swift
import UIKit

class ReportsVC: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = ReportView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

This is my `AppDelegate`:

```swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        if let window = window{
            let reportsVC = ReportsVC()
            navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: reportsVC)
            window.rootViewController = navigationController
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

I tried changing the background color from the `ViewController` itself just to check, but it stayed the same.

Comment: Did you remove the Main.storyboard and update the project's "Main Interface" setting on the General tab so it doesn't reference any storyboard?

Comment: Yes, Sir I did.

Comment: From your code, the only place you are setting a view background is (1) in the view, not it's controller, and (2) it's white. Where in `ReportsVC` are you trying to change it to something else?

Comment: @dfd I know, I want to keep the view and view controller code seperated. I want to design the view in the ReportView, and add it to the ViewController. 2. I tried just to see if it changes the background color, but it didn't.

Comment: OK, a clarification - maybe I'm misreading your question. When you set things in `loadView` it's white. Are you trying to change it after that? If so, where? EDIT: One last thing: `ReportView` isn't necessarily global in scope. I think doing `view = ReportView()` merely sets it more locally in scope. Try creating a more global variable (`let reportView = ReportView()` and then in `loadView` use view = ReportView`.

Comment: @dfd nope, I want to set the color of the background in ReportView, and just use it as the ViewControllers view, so I keep the design code in seperate file from the ViewController

Comment: @dfd Thanks, I tried that too, but it didn't work

Comment: I actually have no issues getting your code to run. The only difference I have is I'm setting the `window` background color to white and the `ReportView` to green in the init. I tried with the AppDelegate code being couched in a if statement (and not), with a Main.storyboard (ad without), and with a LaunchScreen.storyboard there (or not). My best guess is to put a breakpoint on `let reportsVC = ReportsVC()` and see if it gets hit. In case if I'm doing something different than you, here's my repo: https://github.com/justdfd/BackgroundColor

Comment: @dfd Thanks, I looked at your code and I don't see anything different from what I did. I looked and the Viewcontroller does get the ReportView but the background color is nil for some reson.

Comment: I see no issues and your code runs as it expected 

Comment: @dfd Thank you! and thank you Mojtaba and everyone that tried to help. Appreantly. I just missed deleting the LaunchScreen.storyboard from the plist. I can't believe I just spent so much time on it. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnDoah Do not delete the launch screen storyboard. You need that and it certainly isn't the cause of your issue.

Comment: Upvoting @rmaddy comment. I had things working in 3 different scenarios, after getting a black screen on my very first try and then doing some searching on how to remove storyboards. (1) Having the AppDelegate code in with both Main & LaunchScreen, (2) removing Main, and (3) removing both. Eventually you *will* need something for a launch screen - do not remove it. (FYI - the repo I posted has neither. But I did created a second test project and found all three scenarios work.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your view to the viewcontroller's content view this like :

```
self.view.addSubview(ReportView(frame: self.view.frame))
```

The view needs to have a frame to be visible.

Comment: This shouldn't be needed if the view controller's view is set in `loadView()`.